# How can i get an image overlay on other in other row in compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2rcc.png)the view should look like this .
I used padding and also spacer but was not successfull.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xl3Yx.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.